# Find whether $\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}$

First I tried to find whether $|a_n|$ converges:

$$\lim \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}} = \lim \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}} = 1$$

So they both diverge. I then applied Leibniz's criteria:

$$i) \lim b_n = \lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}} = 0 $$
$$ii) b_{n+1} \le b_n \forall n > d$$

d isn't specified so I assumed it is 1, given that this is a series. Then I solved the condition and got $n \le -1/2$. So does it converge or not? It states that n has to be greater than d but I don't know what d is. What went wrong?

Comment: If you start from $n=2$, the sum converges (to just under $0.36953$) but the sum of the absolute values does not.

Answer (score 4):

The series is not absolutely convergent. But it is convergent by the alternating series test. You only have to observe that $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n^{2}-1} }$ decreases to $0$.

It is not absolutely convergent because $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n^{2}-1}} \geq \frac 1 {n}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: And that it is monotonically decreasing :)

Comment: I said 'decreases to $0$, didn't I? @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: Oh I see, I must have misinterpreted it as "converges to $0$"

Comment: I think it can be confusing, because "$a_n$ decreases to $0$" could also mean that $a_n > 0$ and $a_n \to 0$. (+1)

Comment: @Botond A sequence $(a_n)$ decreases if $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$. I don't see how this can be confusing.

Comment: Well, I've heard the "$a_n$ decreases to $0$" expression before when the limit of a positive sequence was zero.

Answer (score 0):

As @Henry stated above, based on Riemann rearrangement theorem, the series converges to whatever number you like, but the sum of absolute values of series diverges because

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}} \ge \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n-1}\ge\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x-1)$$